How do I fix characters produced in python by Polars and TQDM?
I'm currently using Emacs 29.3 through the terminal using iTerm2 on a Mac. I'm having issues with the terminal producing what looks like escape codes when printing out a polars dataframe or when using tqdm (progress bar library). Example:

When I run python directly from iTerm2, everything looks normal, so I'm inclined to believe it is a problem with my terminal (emulation?) setup. How can I get it to look as intended? Note: I'm using multi-term currently, but I get these results with term, and ansi-term. eshell gives ? instead of the escape codes.
